# Does numeric promotion apply to constants in Java?

Tags: java, constants

[§5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) and [§5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) do not mention how numeric promotion and widening work for constants.

The following gives an error as expected:

```
short a = 2;
short b = 3;
short s = a + b; // error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to short
```

But if they are declared final, it compiles without error:

```
final short a = 2;
final short b = 3;
short s = a + b; // no error
```

Why is that? And which section of the specs explains that?

My guess is that they are compile time constants and therefore treated as integers.

Comment: Off to find the duplicate. The answer is: Compiler-time [constant expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

Comment: this should work `short s = (short) (a + b);` without final in a and b

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It is different because I am asking about numeric promotion. Linked question is asking directly about casting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Promotion necessarily must be done by the compiler because [there are no JVM instructions for addition of `short`s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings).

However, the compiler is able to narrow the resulting integer sum to a short because:

> If the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte,
>   short, char, or int ... a narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the
>   variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant
>   expression is representable in the type of the variable.

as described [in the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3).

Adding `final` determines whether or not it's a constant expression.